# calculate datetime + days but make it to until 12 am in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, datetime, amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift and I want to calculate the `exp_date_final` by adding the `exp_date` with `to_days`.

my query is:

```
select exp_date,
       to_days,
       (exp_date + to_days) as exp_date_final
from data
```

and it results like this:

```
exp_date              to_days       exp_date_final
12 June 2023 17.00       2          14 June 2023 17.00
13 June 2023 14.00       3          16 June 2023 14.00
14 June 2023 13.00       2          16 June 2023 15.00
```

However, I want to make the `exp_date_final` hours to 24.00 on that day.
The desire results would be like this:

```
exp_date              to_days       exp_date_final
12 June 2023 17.00       2          14 June 2023 24.00
13 June 2023 14.00       3          16 June 2023 24.00
14 June 2023 13.00       2          16 June 2023 24.00
```

How should I write my query in order to get the desired datetime?

Thank you in advance

Comment: A time of "24.00" doesn't exist -- it would actually be "00.00" on the next day. So, your output is not possible if you wish to display a pure timestamp. Are you okay with showing `00.00` on the next day, or do you want to fake it by showing the time as hard-coded text?

Answer (score 0):

You should use DATEADD function
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html

```
select 
       exp_date,
       to_days,
       dateadd(day, to_days, exp_date) as exp_date_final
from data
```

Comment: thanks. But i tried,and it didnt work

Comment: hours interval in datetime is from 0 to 23

Comment: if you need discard time from datetime simple convert datetime type to date type. You can use CAST function